# how to send mail when user submit form in php

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, sendmail, auto-responder

im sending mail from Form  when the vistor submited the form. now email is working fine. how can i send mail to who submited form mean auto response to the Visitor email id at the same time.plz help me to do.

**here my code.**

```html
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return submitdata()"  method="post" >
  <fieldset>
 <div class="col-xs-6">
      
       <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name"required />
      </div>
 
 <div class="col-xs-6">
     
      <input class="form-control input-sm" type="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*"  name="emailid" placeholder="Enter your email"required/>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6">
      
      <input  class="form-control input-sm"type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required />
      </div>
 
 <div class="col-xs-6">
     
      <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City"required/>
      </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   <select id="mark" name="mark" class="form-control">
        <option>Select Department</option>
    <option  value="fashion">FASHION DESIGN</option>
    <option value="interior">INTERIOR DESIGN</option>

  </select>
      </div>
 
 <div class="col-xs-6">
     
      
  <select id="series" class="form-control" name="series">
          <option class="fashion" value="">Select Courses</option>

          <optgroup class="fashion"  label="University Courses" >
         

          <option value="MSc:Fashion Design(2 Years)" class="fashion">MSc: Fashion Design(2 Years)</option>
          <option value="BSc:Fashion Design ( 3 Years)" class="fashion">BSc: Fashion Design ( 3 Years)</option>
          <option value="Advanced Diploma:Fashion Design ( 2 Years)" class="fashion">Advanced Diploma: Fashion Design ( 2 Years)</option>
          <option value="Diploma:Fashion Design  (1 Year)" class="fashion">Diploma: Fashion Design  (1 Year)</option>
            </optgroup>
         <optgroup  class="fashion"  label="IMB (Milan,Italy) Courses">   
          <option value="Specialisation Program: Fashion Design (3 Years)" class="fashion">Specialisation Program: Fashion Design (3 Years)</option>
          <option value="Advanced Program: Fashion Design ( 2 Years)" class="fashion">Advanced Program: Fashion Design ( 2 Years)</option>
          <option value="Foundation Program: Fashion Design ( 1 Year) " class="fashion">Foundation Program: Fashion Design ( 1 Year)</option>
   </optgroup>
    

          <option value="MSc:Interior Design(2 Years)" class="interior">MSc:Interior Design(2 Years)</option>
          <option value="BSc:Interior Design ( 3 Years)" class="interior">BSc:Interior Design ( 3 Years)</option>
          <option value="Advanced Diploma:Interior Design ( 2 Years)" class="interior">Advanced Diploma: Interior Design ( 2 Years)</option>
          <option value="Diploma:Interior Design (1 Year)" class="interior">Diploma:Interior Design (1 Year)</option>
 
 
 </select>
 
 
      </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 ">
    <textarea class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="AcademicQualification" placeholder="Academic Qualification"required></textarea>
    
         
           
        </div>
        
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      
        <textarea class="form-control input-xs" rows="2" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"required></textarea>
      </div>
 
 <div class="col-xs-12">
    
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" name="submit" value="Send" onclick="submitForm()">Send</button>
  
      </div>
   
</fieldset>
 
</form>
```

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

$message=
'Name           : ' .$_POST['name'].'        <br />
Email           : ' .$_POST['emailid'].'     <br />
Phone           : ' .$_POST['phone'].'        <br />
City            : ' .$_POST['city'].'         <br />
Interested in   : ' .$_POST['mark'].'         <br />
Selected Courses: ' .$_POST['series'].'         <br />
Academic Qualification:  ' .$_POST['AcademicQualification'].'         <br />
Comments        :       '.$_POST['comments'].'   <br />

';
    require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class
      
    // Instantiate Class  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  
      
    // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';
    
     // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "jaganrao44@gmail.com"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "xxxxxxxxxx"; // Your Gmail password
      
    // Compose

    $mail->Subject = "New Admission Enquiry Form";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
  
    // Send To  
 
    $mail->AddAddress("jaganrao44@gmail.com", "Recipient Name"); // Where to send it - Recipient
 
 
 
 
 
 
    $result = $mail->Send();  // Send!  
 $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      

}
?>
```

Comment: If this is a publicly accessible form, dont do it - bots could use your server to spam random email accounts

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer and you've based your code on an obsolete example. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and look at the examples provided with it. You also need to set the From address before this will work, but do not use the submitters address as the from address - put theirs into reply-to and yours in From.

Comment: thanks Steve. now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a duplicate email you can just add another name:

```
$mail->AddAddress('recipient1@domain.com', 'First Name');
$mail->AddAddress('recipient2@domain.com', 'Second Name');
```

OR you can create another instance of phpmailer and loop through both emails individually in order to send one at a time.

Comment: Or you can simply re-use the same PHPMailer instance to send a second message to a different set of recipients - see the `clearAllRecipients()` method.

Comment: @Synchro Good call!